# Why The Unity3d Facebook SDK Does Not Recognize Android SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine

The Facebook settings tab in Unity (after installing the facebook sdk) says the Android SDK is not setup. However, prior to installing the Facebook SDK I had no issues with this and have built numerous APKs for testing purposes. The Android SDK paths are still there in my external tools section.

I was hoping someone who has experienced this before could point me in the right direction. I'm not sure if it's a version conflict, or if it's just one of Unity's many shenanigans. I've attached a screenshot of the error message and the SDK paths below.

[SDK Error And Locations Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDLBa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's some bug with Facebook SDK, just Uncheck "Installed with Unity" for Android SDK and check it again and warning will disappear, still I don't think it causes any errors

Comment: I'd up vote if I could. :) I tried this, it brought up the dependency resolver. Still didn't work. I downloaded android studio and used the SDK from that. Toggled the "Installed With Unity" box again, dependency resolver popped up again. This time the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the very same thing; apparently, it is about the way Facebook API is looking for your android SDK, but I don't have much more detail. I found some help here:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/you-dont-have-android-sdk-setup-facebbok-sdk.835435/

Deselect the default build-in Android SDK and replace it with another one.
Sorry for not being more helpful, in my case Unity detected another SDK right after unchecking the default SDK Tool and it is working now.

Please note that Unity will be fine with the built-in SDK; it's just a Facebook issue and it exists as of the time of posting this answer.